# Git Compatibility Switches?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Does Git provide a compatibility switch to match the workflow of, for example, subversion? I was hoping for something like `git -svncompat checkout` and `git -svncompat checkin`. I know Git has some other svn related switches.

I hope the compatibility is there because the checkout/change/checkin workflow is great for me - its simple (it matches my mental model) and it closely follows my tasks (its my workflow). Plus, it matches this particular project's central repository model (versus the distributed versioning model).

Just in case: like many others before me, I have to work with a git repository and use git - I have no choice. RTFM is out of the question at the moment. I have about 2500 pages of reading to do, so I won't have time to read a book on git for a couple of months. (Not meant to start a war - its simply my circumstance at the moment).

Jeff

Comment: short answer: no. Git works very differently to svn, as it is decentralized. You will have to learn at least some basics of git.

Comment: Thanks Chronial. I was afraid of that. (And let the down votes begin because I asked if a switch exists! I must have pissed off a git fan boi:)

Comment: You shouldn't need to read very much. It does have some annoying conceptual differences but you'll pick it up fairly quickly. The closest to `checkout` is `git clone` and `update` is `git pull`; to commit to an upstream server you need to `git add` the changed files to put them in the staging area, `git commit` to make a local commit from the staging area then `git push` to send the commit to the upstream server.

Comment: Be careful with the “easy switch” approach. You generate a history graph while working with git – a git history is very unlikely to be linear. If you do not understand what you are doing, you can create an ugly mess and your team might be not very happy about that (or not care at all :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as others have pointed out, the answer to your question is "no".

however, you don't need to read an entire book on git, in order to get you going.

there's some documentation tailored specifically for people like you, coming from subversion and wanting (or having) to use git:

- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnCrashCourse
- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/images-git/7/78/Git-svn-cheatsheet.pdf (that's a single page for you to printout and glue to your desk for the first couple of days)

as for your workflow, `git` isn't much different from what you seem to expect: *checkout, edit, checkin*:

the main difference is, that with git, all these things are *local* on your machine, and you need some extra steps around this to synch with an external repository: **pull**, *checkout, edit, checkin*, **push**

(the real differences only start when it comes to branching and merging)